# Github API pull Requests by reviewer using API

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to write an internal tool for my team. For that I need to get all the PR's assigned to an specific Reviewer from the API. So far, I've found the UI on Github has this capability, however, the only way I've found so far is:

1. Using the PR list api

   https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-pull-requests
2. For each one of those PR's call the get Review Requests

   https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/review-requests?apiVersion=2022-11-28
3. Filter the results by user

I was wondering if there's a single API endpoint that I could hit that provides the same results as the Github ui when landing on `pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+user-review-requested%3A%40me+review%3Arequired1`

Thanks a lot for the guidance.